# Model layer dependency on MVC attributes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, model, data-annotations

We have an MVC3 project that uses nHibernate; there is a separate model project that contains all the model classes which is used by the repository and service layers. The models make use of data annotations like DisplayAttribute and RequiredAttribute from System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.

There are also attributes such as RemoteAttribute that are contained in System.Web.Mvc.

This of course means that the model project now has a dependency to a particular front end technology.

Assuming the solution could have other front ends what would be the best way to handle this dependency link?

Comment: Apply those "view specific" attributes only on a corresponding ViewModel, not on the model itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RemoteAttribute` does not belong in the model, since it specifies a controller/action to validate the property on the server, and the model shouldn't have knowledge of concepts like controller, action or route. The presentation layer depends on the model, not the other way around.

I would create a view model that inherits the model, overrides the property (must be virtual) and adds the `RemoteAttribute`. This way you can avoid duplication and mapping, although that's also an alternative.

Comment: Our current view models contain a property that is of the model type. In that instance would another layer of view model be required? One to inherit and override any validation attributes from the original model such as Remote and another view model used by the razor views that contains the data required by the views and a property of the new validation view model?

Answer (score 1):

To reduce dependency between database model and frontend technology, you can use special view model for  validation qnd other front end actions in controller and put data from viewmodel to database entity after it.